# Export sharepoint library to Access 2007

Tags: sharepoint-online

i'm trying to export sharepoint library (infopath forms ) from sharepoint 2007 to ms access 2007 but for some reason it only allows me to export 125 columns and 14,000 rows. 
is there a way to export the full library?

if i try and export a different view then the default view it gives me the following errror: 
You do not have the necessary permissions to use the "library name" object. have your system administrator or the person who created this object establish the appropriate permissions for you. 
but i have created the library view and i am also site collection owner...why do i get the error?